# Can't import statsmodels in Jupyter even though it is already installed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I've installed statsmodels using pip in a terminal. It was successful. 
But then I couldn't import statsmodels in the notebook. 
I also tried running `!pip install statmodels` in the notebook itself. I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: statsmodels in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

But am still unable to import it.

```
import statsmodels as sm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dd062a96f652> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels as sm
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Maybe you need to `import statsmodels.api as sm`?

Comment: @Sraw tried that, didn't work.

Comment: do you have anything more in error message ? Do you have two Pythons on computer ? Do you run notebook on local computer ?

Comment: @furas no. I have only python2.7 (running on Mac OS) and yes this is all local.

Comment: you also have to add ```import statsmodels.robust```. or you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864749/why-cant-i-import-statsmodels-directly

Comment: virtualenv? [this help?](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/813), anaconda? different statsmodels installed? uninstall/reinstall? can you visually see it in site-packages when you go to it? accidentally install statsmodels for python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue yesterday. I installed statsmodels by pip install statsmodels.  [Reference link](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/install.html). I can run it well in Python under cmd environment. However I failed to import it in Jupyter notebook due to the modulNotFoundError. Today, God's magic happens, by restarting the computer and shift from Jupyter Tensorflow to normal Jupyter Notebook, the problem has been solved. Please give a try: Restart the computer, Use General Jupyter Book. Good luck.

Comment: Hey Pinkmei, please read up on [writing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before answering your next question!

Comment: Thank you, hope my updated answer is clearer to those who might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

the statsmodels library requires the computer to be restarted after installation before use in jupyter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).