# StatsModel Library - Import/Attribute Error

Tags: python, installation, importerror, statsmodels

I am having trouble to import the statsmodels library. I've installed it using pip.

```
(base) d:\xxx\Python>pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
Collecting statsmodels
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/ed/714934d2836a8d03859275ce370f249dadb88c74dd74e3f3a888941166ab/statsmodels-0.10.1-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: statsmodels
Successfully installed statsmodels-0.10.1
```

The error is:

```
 import statsmodels
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work. The module exists. I've tried to install it with git but I've got the same error.

EDIT AFTER SOLUTION:

Information about import: [Why can't I import statsmodels directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864749/why-cant-i-import-statsmodels-directly)

My error was on pip. pip doesn't work. Install it with

```
pip3 install statsmodels
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I import statsmodels directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864749/why-cant-i-import-statsmodels-directly)

Comment: Thanks you but the problem was in the python version. pip doesn't work but pip3 yes.

Thanks